# CRUD application with API (how to conf API properly) - Ext-JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a working CRUD application but with U (update) I have a question.

In my store I have:

```
...........

proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create  : '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/create',
            read    : '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/index',
            update  : '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/update',
            destroy : '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/delete'
        },
        actionMethods: {
            create  : 'POST',
            read    : 'POST',
            update  : 'POST',
            destroy : 'POST'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Worker',
            rootProperty: 'Worker',
            successProperty: 'success',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data',
            encode: true
        },

...........
```

When submitting form for editing, I have a url specified:

```
....
panel.getForm().submit({
            url: '../mega_sabrina_cake/workers/edit',
            success: function(form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', "The Worker has been edited!");

...
```

So, how can I use the **url from the store** to avoid putting url in form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form does not use the store it uses its own submit method to communicate to the server.
If you want to use the Store or Model proxy (you can define the same proxy config on the Model as you did on the store) you can do the following:

form.updateRecord(record) and use store.sync() or [model.save()](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Model-method-save)

here is an example you could follow: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/writer/writer.html